# Is proving g o f being surjective for one element = all elements are surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

**The task:**

Let E,F and G be given sets and let the functions f : E → F and g : F → G be given. Observe the claim:

f is surjective and g is surjective => g o f is surjektive. The claim is either true or false. If it is true, prove it, if it is false, prove it.

**So I know this to be true. My solution is:**

Each element in F has a pre-image of E in the function f, and each element in G has a pre-image of F in the function g.

Let x belong to G, then there exists an x1 that belongs to F such that g(x1)=x. F is surjective and x1 belongs to F => there is an x2 that belongs to E such that f(x2)=x1 => g(f(x2)) = x. Hence g o f is onto.

But my issue is: Haven't I just proved for one element and not for all elements? I've only proven for an element x, not necessarily for every element in f and g. Or is it automatically proved for every element since the funtion is surjective?

Answer (score 1):

Since you imposed *no* restriction on $x$, you proved (correctly) that *every* $x\in G$ has a pre-image with respect to $g\circ f$ and that therefore $g\circ f$ is surjective.

Comment: Does this mean that x in G is every element in G? I mean when I say x in G, it implies that x are all elements in G and not just one element?

Comment: No, since I don't know what that means. What I wrote means that you proof works for every element of $G$.

Comment: And the reason it works for every element in G is because of the surjectivity?

Comment: No. It is the other way around: since it works for every element of $G$, $g\circ f$ is surjective.